# Python - Creating new model objects leads to updating previously created objects

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to create a model called CampaignProfile, then each logged in user can fill in a form to build such an object, and have all of their 'CampaignProfile's displayed on their personal dashboard.

What I've found is that when I fill in this form then a new CampaignProfile object is not created like I need, but instead the information entered (title, etc) replaces the first CampaignProfile made.

I'm struggling to understand why the model object is being updated as opposed to creating a new object.

Models.py:

```
def get_file_name(instance, filename):
    return ('uploads/%s_%s' % (str(time())).replace('.','_'), filename)

class CampaignProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserModel, related_name='campaignprofile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    campaign_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Title')
    campaign_dt_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date Created')
    campaign_dt_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Date Updated')
    campaign_docs = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_name, verbose_name='Files', blank=True, null=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Campaign Profile'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Campaign Title: ' + self.campaign_title + ' - ' + str(self.user)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user is None:  # Set default reference
            self.user = UserModel.objects.get(id=pk)
        super(CampaignProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Forms.py

```
class NewCampaignForm(forms.ModelForm):
    campaign_title = forms.CharField(min_length=1, max_length=80, label='Campaign Name', required=True,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus':'autofocus'}))
    campaign_docs = forms.FileField(label='Attach .png and .docx files to your campaign', required=False,
    widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'id':'fileupl'}))

    class Meta:
        model = CampaignProfile
        fields = ['campaign_title', 'campaign_docs']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(NewCampaignForm, self).clean()
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        campaign = super(NewCampaignForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            campaign.save()
        return campaign
```

Views.py

```
def campaign_create(request):
    user=request.user.id
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            campaign = request.user.campaignprofile
        except CampaignProfile.DoesNotExist:
            campaign = CampaignProfile(user)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = NewCampaignForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=campaign)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('/dashboard/')
            else:
                form = NewCampaignForm(instance=campaign)
            return render(request, 'campaign-create.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            form = NewCampaignForm()
        return render(request, 'campaign-create.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('/users/login/')
```

I get no errors when I submit the form, and have tried a few different things with the code.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've defined the relationship to User as one-to-one. By definition, that means a user can only have one profile.

If you want to allow multiple profiles, use a ForeignKey instead.

Comment: I changed the OneToOneField to a ForeignKey and removed 'instance=campaign' from my views.py, however this time when I submit the form it just returns an empty form, and doesn't create a new profile object, nor update the old object. Any ideas on why it doesn't save the new form entries?

Comment: Well, presumably the form is not valid, but you've hidden any errors by re-instantiating the form in the else clause. Don't do that.